# How to post form.body in JSONArray using OkHttp?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

Hi guys I was trying to post a `JSONArray` using OkHttp. I want to do like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "john"
  },
  {
    "food": "burger"
  }
]
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: what you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a `JSONObject` in an array and then pass it to your `JSONArray`.

Something like this:

```
JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

JSONObject js = new JSONObject();
try {
    js.put("name", "john");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
list.put(js);

js = new JSONObject();
try {
    js.put("food", "burger");
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
list.put(js);

Log.e(TAG, "found json array " + list);
```

and if you have more items, then run the `js' in a loop until you are done with it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution sir. Much appreciate it!

Answer (score -1):

Something like this:

```
public void sendRequest(String route) {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    String url = baseUrl + route;

    RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addFormDataPart("username", String.valueOf(username.getText()))
            .addFormDataPart("password", String.valueOf(password.getText()))
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .build();

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
            Log.d("Error", "Something Went Wrong");
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String myresponse = response.body().string();
                try {
                    JSONArray all = new JSONArray(myresponse);
                    // Do whatever
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                String errorBodyString = response.body().string();
                Log.d("Error", errorBodyString);
            }
        }
    });
}
```